# Dart script not working in any IE version

Tags: internet-explorer, dart

This is my very simple dart script:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  String heightClosed = query('.portlet.card div').style.height;

  // Set up card hover events
  queryAll(".portlet.card").forEach((el) {
    el.on.mouseOver.add((e) {
      el.query('div').style.height = '175px';
    });

    el.on.mouseOut.add((e) {
      el.query('div').style.height = heightClosed;
    });

    el.on.click.add((e) {
      String url = el.query('h1 a').attributes['href'];
      window.location.assign(url);
    });
  });

}
```

Javascript Console error in IE9

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'defineProperty'
```

After compiling this to javascript, everything works fine in Chrome & Firefox, but it doesn't work in any version of IE.

Comment: Are there any errors in IE's JavaScript console? Is this sample hosted anywhere? Note that Dart only supports IE9 and above.

Comment: of course, my bad, will update the post with the error

Comment: I just upgraded my dart editor (and api), recompiled the js, and now it's working as expected. Although, the error still exists for IE 7 & 8, but that's to be expected since they are not supported :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was using an old version of the dart api. Upgraded and re-compiled javascript, then it all worked as expected.